# What is the replacement for range-v3 views::cache1 in std::ranges?

Tags: c++, std-ranges

Is there any replacement for range-v3 [views::cache1](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1views_1_1cache1__fn.html) in `std::ranges`?

Caching the most recent element could be quite helpful when it comes to heavy calculation for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.

However, [P2760: A Plan for C++26 Ranges](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2760r1.html) sets it to *Tier 1* priority and may rename it as [`cache_last`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2760r1.html#cache_last) which is more compliant with the standard naming, so hopefully we will see it in C++26.

And there is a paper that introduces `cache_last`, namely [P3138](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2024/p3138r0.html).